# Problems to access an API in R

Tags: r, api

I am trying to download some data from an API.
Following the site documentation:

```
library(jsonlite)
document <- fromJSON("https://api.gurufocus.com/public/user/{your personal token?}/stock/WMT/keyratios");
epv <- document$Valuation$`EPV`
cat(epv)
```

I inserted my token, but unfortunately, I get this error:
Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : HTTP error 404.

Any idea to solve this problem?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up front: remove the `{`, `?}` from the url.

---

Replace more of the string. If you notice in [their examples](https://www.gurufocus.com/api.php):

```
Request
Method    URL
GET       https://api.gurufocus.com/public/user/{your personal token?}/stock/{symbol?}/financials
Example   https://api.gurufocus.com/public/user/{your personal token?}/stock/WMT/financials
```

The `{symbol?}` is replaced with `WMT`. I'm inferring you need to do with same with your token.

If I call

```
https://api.gurufocus.com/public/user/{abcd1234?}/stock/WMT/financials
```

(where `abcd1234` is a known fake token), I get a 404 Not Found. I believe this is because the question mark breaks the URL into a path component

```
https://api.gurufocus.com/public/user/{abcd1234
```

and arguments

```
}/stock/WMT/financials
```

However, when I do:

```
https://api.gurufocus.com/public/user/abcd1234/stock/WMT/financials
```

I get a 401 Unauthorized, meaning that it parsed a token out of it, found the endpoint, and the token is not sufficient (which I know) to authorize access.

Comment: thanks for your response.. so, what do you suggest to do? I inserted the real API...and I got this 401 error

Comment: Use `https://api.gurufocus.com/public/user/abcd1234/stock/WMT/financials` (replacing `abcd1234` with your real token. (That is, remove the `{` and `?}` from the URL.